# Product Version for Analysis Services and Report Server using T SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017, ssrs, ssas

How can I find the product version for both analysis services and report server using Transact-SQL?

I'm trying to put together a query that will get me the details of each SQL instance with their product versions. At the moment I have the following:

```
  SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS InstanceName,
  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion
  SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS Edition,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductLevel') AS ProductLevel,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateLevel') AS ProductUpdateLevel,
  SERVERPROPERTY('ProductUpdateReference') AS ProductUpdateReference
  --    Analysis Services Product Version
  --    Report Server Product Version
```

I'm sure it is not using SERVERPROPERTY as I've looked at the Microsoft Doc's and I have looked at the other property types and have either missed what I'm looking for or not asking the right question.

Comment: The SSRS version is displayed on the Reporting Services Web Service URL, for example: http://servername/reportserver. Could you write some code to load that page and parse the results for the version number? It's not a one-liner, but it's a start.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626173/how-to-determine-sql-server-version-on-a-reporting-server for some other non-T-SQL approaches. But I'll keep looking for a T-SQL solution for you.

Comment: Keep in mind that SSRS and AS can be installed independently of the SQL Server database engine, which is why there is no T-SQL solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm no good at coding and just started getting my hands stuck into PowerShell.  Don't know where I would start with the other stackoverflow solution.  Thanks Doug.